# Avatar photo of a user too... Revealing. In a bad sexualized way. What should be the right action?

Tags: discussion, gravatar

While browser the meta section, I've found something quite disturbing.

Before anything, I must say that I am a male.

And I found a female avatar that is too revealing.
It shows a lot of cleavage.
It isn't obscene by itself, but it isn't the right image.

I know we are free to post the avatar we wish, but this disturbed me.

An image like that wouldn't be suited for Facebook, let alone a website to share ideas and solve problems.

I don't really want to reveal the username in question, but if required I will reveal in a comment.

Exposing the issue, what is the right actions to take when seeing such avatar?

---

While the title only refers about an 'improper' image, it is actually talking about an obscene image.

The user's avatar isn't obscene *by itself*. But it is revealing and may lead to it's sexualization.

---

Also, the question is asking if the O.P. can flag the question, while this question is to know what is the right action to take.

Comment: That is highly depending on the culture of the viewer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217926/discussion-on-question-by-ismael-miguel-avatar-photo-of-a-user-too-revealing).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to judge cleavage without seeing it, but the best action for everyone involved is *most likely* to ignore it and move on.

If you're *very* bothered, you can always flag the profile for moderator attention (by flagging any contribution of theirs, regardless of quality, and explaining in the flag text what your issue is), or E-Mail `team@stackoverflow.com`.

However, they're unlikely to take action unless it's really, really grossly indecent: Stack Exchange's general policy towards Gravatars has always been very liberal.

The final decision about whether a Gravatar has to be forcibly removed will be with moderators and/or Stack Exchange, Inc., whose private property these web sites are.

Comment: I see. But I can't find where to flag it or I would have done it before bothering you all with this question.

Comment: @Ismael flag any contribution by the user and explain in the text field what's up.

Comment: I will look for a 'bad' contribution from said user and I will flag it. May require a lot of digging.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel no need to find a "bad" contribution; just make sure you explain clearly what you are flagging.

Comment: Never thought a Meta answer would start *"It's hard to judge cleavage without seeing it'* - you're so transparent ;o)

Comment: Thank you, I will do exactly that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well, that sentence may have 2 meanings. But he is correct, since a huge cleavage for me may be perfectly natural for someone else. But I'm not putting a quantity in it. I'm just saying that there is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe hmm. That puts a completely new spin on ["I know pornography when I see it"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it) :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 What kind of spin?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel we're just kidding around - that sentence "I know it when I see it" is a famous quote from a Supreme Court justice on a obscenity-related court case (see the link) and following Jon's interpretation above it could be read as a *request to get to see pornography* rather than a statement about how to judge it.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I got it all, expect the spin part. But don't bother. It isn't related to the question (which is dead anyway).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel in case you're interested, it's an English idiom: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/put+a+spin+on

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you a lot for the link. I wasn't aware of such idiom.

Comment: @Pekka웃 And here I thought you were talking about spinner pornography…

Comment: @abarnert lol, I had to look that up and found a definition in a glossary titled "From A to what you don't want to know".

Comment: @abarnert You dirtied my mind. Now I can't stop puzzling myself on how it would be possible.

Comment: @Pekka웃 At least you didn't look it up and find Urban Dictionary; I haven't checked, but I'd be willing to bet they go out of their way to define it in the most graphic and offensive way possible, with links to even more things you don't want to know…

Comment: @abarnert Like what?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I think that demonstrates that the real problem here is with you. Things existing in the world doesn't make you dirty. Knowing about those things doesn't make you dirty. If you can't handle living in a world where people walk around in outfits like that LRIO's without constant "sessions of *self-care*", that's not the world's fault.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: If you really want to know, go search Urban Dictionary. I'm guessing you will need to spend the rest of the day scrubbing your skin with the harshest soap you can find, though; even people who are open and liberal tend to have that reaction to that site…

Comment: @abarnert Obscene words don't have effect on me. And I never said I wasn't the problem. But I'm saying that the image isn't the right one. Also, I'm not here to point out every single tiny obscene or revealing thing. I saw a image that shocked me and I asked what I should do. By the way, who is LRIO?

Comment: Wake up and smell the acronym, @Ismael.

Comment: _"You dirtied my mind"_ I don't understand whatever happened to that old concept of taking responsibility for oneself?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Can't take a joke, right?

Comment: @Ismael: You're the one here who can't "take" things.

Comment: I think advice to email is wrong (outdated); as far as I can tell, it has been replaced with [contact us](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contact) channel (I used the latter and it worked pretty well to me)

Comment: @gnat `team@stackoverflow.com` works fine, I used it only a week ago and got Tim Post on the line :)

Comment: hm upon re-checking, [both ways seem to be equally okay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140394/165773); I probably simply misinterpreted when they changed mailto to contact form in Help Center

Answer (score 7):

It's tough to find a *right* action, because cleavage and sexualization are not absolute. Those are subjective terms, different cultures and different people may see them differently. And while it would be cool to satisfy every single culture on the planet, that will never work. So we will have to compromise.

An avatar is not even 1cm x 1cm on my screen. So what exactly are we talking about? Is two pixels cleavage ok, but three pixels is too many? Or how about four? Is five pixels already borderline pornography? The point is that an avatar is an icon at best.

The avatar is a representation of the guy or girl at the other end of the internet. If you don't like it, don't answer the questions or upvote the answers. In real life, if someone is inappropriately dressed, you simply turn away and live your own life.

If it goes against any laws or policies of the site, feel free to flag it. If it does not and you simply don't like it, don't interact with that user.

Comment: Well, I can assure you it is a lot more than 5 pixels. It would be cool, but there's things you can easily 'fix' and some that you can't. For this situation, a photo with a top covering the cleavage would fix it. But no, i'm happy browsing here and I am caught with that avatar.

Comment: Well, now that I've seen the avatar in question, I don't think that flagging would help. Because where I live, this could be a normal street outfit (at least spring to autumn). Does it look good? Definetly. Is it inappropriate? Where I live, it would not be. So what do we base our decision on? The most restrictive religion, government or personal belief? I don't think so. We would all be using grey boxes as avatars then.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far, but perhaps cutting the cleavage in half would be something more presentable.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel maybe. I'm not a big fan of the picture, but I don't think it goes against any official policies. Dressing differently would make the picture more presenatable to you personally. What if the next user does not like open hair? Or glasses? Or smiling? There's millions of users, a photo catering to all of them at once would probably be a grey box, offending only the tiny fraction of people believing you should not take pictures of grey boxes.

Comment: I honestly don't want to see gray boxes everywhere, but I'm not expecting to see cleavage in a respectable website. There are other places for such content. Which, sadly, are very easily found. But that doesn't matter. But we must agree that the percentage of people who don't like such things is really too inferior. (I don't like that much of photos with people smilling, and I'm not complaining about it.)

Comment: I *will* defend this user's rights to have an avatar to his/her liking, not because I like it or not, but because the next step may be banning mine for having long hair as a dude, my tattoos, my mischievous smile, or the fact I have a middle finger *on each hand*.

Comment: @Jongware If you had a photo presenting only the middle-finger raised, I would protest the same way.

Answer (score 5):

Is there really that image exist or this question is only for gaining publicity because even if that image exist its her choice what she want to show and what not.

Everyone is free to represent the way they want and if you have any issue then you should avoid that user

Comment: I do avoid the user. But I was simply reading on meta and I got that by surprise. And it indeed exists. But there is a certain level to what you can show.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: no, not "**there is** a level ...". You should make that "*I feel*.." Others may feel it even stronger, or less, or not care about it at all.

Comment: @Jongware I know that. That's why I didn't put a quantity. There's nothing saying "Look, there's a huge cleavage right there." but I'm simply pointing out it's presence.

Comment: @Ismael: It's really a shame that you "avoid that user". Apparently I've "reached 4.9 million people" with my technical contributions, and you're missing out on them over a kind of sexist fear.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Actually, I avoid you because you are a really toxic person. You Can't take criticism. You treat everybody poorly when people ask you something. This is what I see. It has nothing to do with gender. There's a female moderator in another website that I've always had a pleasing and fun experience.

Comment: Charming. It must be nice being so perfect, huh? I think I shall just ignore you now, @Ismael. I suggest you continue to do the same.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sadly, I'm not perfect. Nobody is. I wish I was. But it doesn't matter. Just please, stop being toxic.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Why is it that when someone accuses someone else of being "toxic", they are almost always being a complete hypocrite?

Answer (score 2):

A female user is free to present herself in any way she wants. If that includes using an avatar image *of herself* that other users find "too revealing", these other users must accept it.

**Edit:** Of course illegal content must be handled. But I highly doubt that too much cleavage that is *not pornographic*, *not even obscene*, is anything that should be banned from SO.

Comment: Umm.... hardly. A seriously pornographic gravatar would not be appropriate on the SE network, and would probably have to be censored for *legal* reasons if nothing else. And how exactly do you plan to find out whether the user is actually a her, and it's actually a real photo of them?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I agree, but it isn't pornographic. It is revealing. And I think it is disrespectful.

Comment: "disrespectful" to who?

Comment: @TZHX A^t the very least, to me. And it really kinda stains the image of StackOverflow, in my opinion, for letting a sexualized image to flow freely.

Comment: I consider it disrepectful that you don't accept her choice of avatar.

Comment: I think calling the image in question "sexualised" is being dramatic.

Comment: @Tichodroma I accept the choice, I just was shocked and didn't knew what to do. I really wasn't expecting such content in a respectful environment.

Comment: @TZHX It should be saying `possibly sexualized`.

Comment: You are shocked by cleavage? Come on, how do women dress over in Portugal in the summer? Do they all wear nuns clothes?

Comment: @Tichodroma Sadly, they exibit too much (specially 12-18 years old). If I'm socked with some things I see outside? Yes. Does that change anything? NO! But most of the shock was a mix of the image and the environment itself in the website. It wasn't just because it shows more than nothing.

Comment: God forbid that stackoverflow allow human images to flow freely. I completely agree those glasses on that girl are offensive. We have to draw a line somewhere. Otherwise what's next? Image of wild animals face palming in plain sight?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel aren't you the one sexualizing the image though?

Comment: @sehe I'm serious. There was no sarcasm...

Comment: @jalf No, I'm just saying that some may sexualize it.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Do think I'm not serious? I'm trying to tell you there's a problem with your thinking. I mean, if my avatar turns you on, I'll accept that. Re.: "I'm not the one sexualizing it": By going out of your way to accomodate some people who might apparently think it's bad that "some" (others?!) "may sexualize it" you're lending it credibility. Personally, I think that's reinforcing the problem. Why make it ours?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: And you're suggesting that (a) they should not, and (b) we should not accidentally put them in a position where they _could_ ... why, exactly? Maybe you don't but I live in a free country where you can sexualise whatever you like.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think this is getting too toxic and salty. I think it is enough interaction between us.

Comment: "Salty": What do you mean?

Comment: Sure, just drive-by assault everybody's freedom, rights and principles then run away when called out on it.